# How to handle oversized JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog, scrollpane

I'm developing a `JDialog` which will have three sections, one on the top of the other: customer general information, list of customer addresses and list of orders.

The list of customer addresses may grow arbitrarily large and this causes the dialog to grow beyond the screen height.

Thus, calling `pack()` before displaying it does not work because the packed dialog height is still too big for the screen height.

This calls for a scroll pane. But I would have to set the dialog's preferred size to take advantage of it, and defining a size for it depends on the display resolution. I'm not sure how to do that.

How should I handle this scenario?

[image: the oversized dialog]

Comment: Use `JScrollPane` Luke!

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I did and it didn't work. I need to define dimensions for the dialog beforehand and I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: A better approach to this than guessing the sizes needed, is to display the results in a `JList` and call the [`setVisibleRowCount(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html#setVisibleRowCount(int)) method. (With a `JScrollPane` as suggested by @SergiyMedvynskyy.)

Comment: Just to clear up a possible confusion, I'm using `JScrollPane` and it is working after @IvanKukic's answer. I'll consider using a `JList` with `setVisibleRowCount(int)`. Thanks.

Comment: *"Just to clear up a possible confusion"* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @SergiyMedvynskyy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry, I was addressing you initially (the choice for `JList`), but it started just as a general comment with the intent to clarify things for whoever reads this question.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy I'm using `JScrollPane`. It didn't work initially but after calling `setPreferredSize()` passing a fraction of the screen resolution it worked. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can use `Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` to get the screen size and then size the dialog proportionally (and place the content in a `JScrollPane`).

Second, I'd suggest adding some kind of collapse on items so you only see the ones you are actually interested in.

Comment: Thanks! I've added it before `pack()` and it worked.